# good terminology for the parameters of a lognormal distribution?

Tags: terminology, lognormal-distribution, parameterization

Is there any good short terminology for the two parameters of a lognormal distribution?

I have been using **mean-log** for $\mu$ and **volatility** for $\sigma$, where the lognormal variable $X$ has $\ln(X)$ distributed normally with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

This terminology is not standard, but then neither [Mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognormal-distribution.html) nor [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogNormalDistribution.html) nor [NIST](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3669.htm) nor [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) seems to have any standard phrases of similar length for these quite common parameters.

1. **Mean-log** has the advantages of being short, clear, and parallel to the well-established meaning of "mean square". It may not be parallel to the word "lognormal", but I still find it preferable to the alternative:

   - "log-mean" would suggest $\ln(E(X))$.
2. **Volatility** works well for one common use of the lognormal    distribution, e.g. modeling relative stock prices in one year by a lognormal distribution with mean-log 8.5% and volatility 19.5%. But this does not work so well for lognormal models of StackExchange votes or storm sizes.  On the other hand, I find this preferable to the convolutedness or awkwardness of the alternatives:

   - "modeling relative stock prices in one year by a lognormal
     distribution whose log has mean 8.5% and standard deviation 19.5%"
   - "standard deviation of the log of the variable of 19.5%"
   - "s.d.-log of 19.5%"
   - "shape of 19.5%" (would one ever say that a normal distribution had a shape of 19.5%?)
   - "sigma of 19.5%"

Does any one have any better short terminology to suggest?

Comment: "Volatility" is special to finance--most other application domains don't use that term.

Comment: When I have to name them at all (beyond "mu" and "sigma") I call them the log-mean and log-standard-deviation, or sometimes "mean on the log scale" and "standard deviation on the log scale". I also sometimes refer to them respectively as the "scale parameter" and the "shape parameter" (though more strictly $\exp(\mu)$ is a scale parameter rather than $\mu$ itself, most people seem to catch on to the intent).

Comment: @Glen_b, “log-scale sd” would work for me

Comment: I could post the above as an answer if you want. But it's not really something I can claim is any kind of convention.

Answer (score 1):

While not necessarily anything like a real convention, when I have to name the parameters at all (beyond "mu" and "sigma") I tend to call them the log-mean and log-standard-deviation (and I have seen at least a few other people do something similar), or sometimes "mean on the log scale" and "standard deviation on the log scale".

I also sometimes refer to them respectively as the "scale parameter" and the "shape parameter" (though more strictly exp(μ) is a scale parameter rather than μ itself, most people seem to catch on to the intent).